# Linked API to get all members of a group

Tags: api, linkedin-api

How can I get all the members belonging to a particular group or company with Linked API's.
I looked at the Groups API provided by linked it but it does not provide information to pull the member information.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently supported via the API.